# Trying to import a csv into MySQL but getting - Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to import a large csv file into a MySQL database via Workbench but running into this error

```
Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5276: ordinal not 
in range(128)
```

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks

Comment: The csv is likely uff-8. Maybe this will help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-character-set

Comment: Try the same with Mysql Workbench 8.0.21, which you can download from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ - my guess is that it will work.